# SQL pivot based on two "for" columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to pivot the following data based on both the `ratetype` and `costtype` columns. I can't seem to figure out how to do this, without perhaps concatenating the `ratetype` and `costtype` values together, then doing a pivot on that...

Can it be done a better way?

```
Employee  Period  RateType  CostType  Value
--------------------------------------------
1         201701  Rate1     CostA     500
1         201701  Rate1     CostB     700
1         201701  Rate2     CostA     400
1         201701  Rate2     CostB     200
```

into

```
Employee  Period  Rate1CostA  Rate1CostB  Rate2CostA  Rate2CostB
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1         201701  500         700         400         200
```

The only way I can figure out doing it with by concatenating the two fields first, which feels ugly. Something like...

```
SELECT 
    Employee,
    Period,
    Rate1CostA, Rate1CostB,
    Rate2CostA, Rate2CostB
FROM 
    (SELECT
         Employee,
         Period,
         RateType + CostType as RateCostType,
         Value
     FROM
         MyTable) CostRate
PIVOT 
    (MAX(Value)
      FOR RateCostType IN (Rate1CostA, Rate1CostB, Rate2CostA, Rate2CostB)
    ) AS p
```

Comment: Woops, you are correct, I'm using MSSQL, I'll update the tags

Answer (score 3):

Conditional aggregation is one approach:

```
SELECT Employee, Period,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RateType = 'Rate1' AND CostType = 'CostA'
                THEN Value
           END) Rate1CostA,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RateType = 'Rate1' AND CostType = 'CostB'
                THEN Value
           END) Rate1CostB,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RateType = 'Rate2' AND CostType = 'CostA'
                THEN Value
           END) Rate2CostA,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RateType = 'Rate2' AND CostType = 'CostB'
                THEN Value
           END) Rate2CostB
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Employee, Period
```